# Parse String to another appropriate type

Tags: kotlin, variable-types

I have some code where I can receive, depending on the case: a `text` , an `integer` (381) or a `decimal` (431.2).

They are all coming as a `string`.

**How can I parse them to `String`, `Int` or `Double` as needed?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should help:

```
fun checkContentType(): Any {
    val data: String = "12.3";
    val ir = data.toIntOrNull();
    if( ir != null ) return ir;
    val dr = data.toDoubleOrNull(); 
    if( dr != null ) return dr;
    return data;
}
```

Also, as @gidds said, another approach would be to extend the `String` **class** and then use the Elvis operator like this:

```
fun String.convertToAppropriateType() = toIntOrNull() ?: toDoubleOrNull() ?: this
```

Comment: thanks @gidds, I added to the answer.